# Convert SQL Query to Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hey can anybody help me to convert this SQL query to codeigniter

```
"SELECT *,
       (select nama_opd from c1db_pegawai.m_opd aopd where p.jabatan_lama_opd = aopd.id) lm_jabatan_lama_opd,
       (select nama_opd from c1db_pegawai.m_opd bopd where p.jabatan_baru_opd = bopd.id) br_jabatan_baru_opd,
       (select unit_kerja from c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja aunit where p.jabatan_lama_unit = aunit.id) lm_jabatan_lama_unit,
       (select unit_kerja from c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja bunit where p.jabatan_baru_unit = bunit.id) br_jabatan_baru_unit
       from sk_mutasi p;
```

Comment: You mean create this query using just the query builder?

Comment: yes, i need to know how put in query builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as marcogmonteiro already pointed out - you really have to use a join here.

Try the following

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('p.*, aopd.nama_opd AS lm_jabatan_lama_opd, bopd.nama_opd AS br_jabatan_baru_opd, aunit.unit_kerja AS lm_jabatan_lama_unit, bunit.unit_kerja AS br_jabatan_baru_unit')
    ->from('sk_mutasi p')
    ->join('c1db_pegawai.m_opd aopd', 'p.jabatan_lama_opd = aopd.id', 'left')
    ->join('c1db_pegawai.m_opd bopd', 'p.jabatan_baru_opd = bopd.id', 'left')
    ->join('c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja aunit', 'p.jabatan_lama_unit = aunit.id', 'left')
    ->join('c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja bunit', 'p.jabatan_baru_unit = bunit.id', 'left')
    ->get();
```

Comment: nice, this is works so flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Using the query builder you can just do this to group those selects.

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->group_start()
        ->select('(SELECT nama_opd FROM c1db_pegawai.m_opd aopd WHERE p.jabatan_lama_opd = aopd.id) AS lm_jabatan_lama_opd')
    ->group_end()
    ->group_start()
        ->select('(SELECT nama_opd from c1db_pegawai.m_opd bopd WHERE p.jabatan_baru_opd = bopd.id) AS br_jabatan_baru_opd')
    ->group_end()
    ->group_start()
        ->select('(SELECT unit_kerja from c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja aunit where p.jabatan_lama_unit = aunit.id) AS lm_jabatan_lama_unit')
    ->group_end()
    ->group_start()
        ->select('(SELECT unit_kerja from c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja bunit where p.jabatan_baru_unit = bunit.id) AS br_jabatan_baru_unit')
    ->group_end()
    ->from('sk_mutasi p')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

You can even go another level deep and just use the query builder to create those sub-selects.

Alternatively you can just use the entire query in a query statement like so:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT *,
       (select nama_opd from c1db_pegawai.m_opd aopd where p.jabatan_lama_opd = aopd.id) lm_jabatan_lama_opd,
       (select nama_opd from c1db_pegawai.m_opd bopd where p.jabatan_baru_opd = bopd.id) br_jabatan_baru_opd,
       (select unit_kerja from c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja aunit where p.jabatan_lama_unit = aunit.id) lm_jabatan_lama_unit,
       (select unit_kerja from c1db_pegawai.m_unit_kerja bunit where p.jabatan_baru_unit = bunit.id) br_jabatan_baru_unit
       from sk_mutasi p')
->result();
```

I'd like to point out that this is probably not a good query, you might get better results just doing a join to get the info from those extra tables.